# issue of breaking words while copying content from .pdf to word file

Tags: pdf, ms-word

I have a .pdf file. I need the content of the .pdf file in a word document. I copied the text from pdf to a newly created word file. The problem i am facing is in the word document the text i get after pasting is breaking the words keeping in view that the text is being displayed on the .pdf file correctly. For example i have this line in the pdf file "9. Distinguish between a strategy, a marketing plan, and a marketing program, illustrating for a local retailer." while in word file i received "Distinguish between a strategy, a marketing plan, and a marketing program, illustra t ing for a local retailer.". How can i solve this issue?

Comment: The PDF has probably been OCR'd incorrectly and is missing the correct fonts.

Comment: This is common, you just need to go through the Word file and clean it up.

Comment: yeah i was wondering whether there is an automatic solution for this exists or not ?